# How to view all nodes that have the same relation to another node?

Tags: views, entities

I'm using Relation for drupal 7 with views. There is a content type 'Review', which has a relation('is a review of') to Listings and Events. What I want is two blocks in the right sidebar on the Review pages, one which shows the reviewed item (which I already have working), and another which shows all other reviews of the same item.

I've tried to create a view which does this, using two joined relationships and a contextual filter, but can't make it work the way I want. The contextual filter is on the Nid of the original review, the first relationship is from the review to the reviewed item (relation target), and the second is from the reviewed item to other reviews (relation source). The second relation has a relationship to the first.

So far I can't make it show anything other than the title of the reviewed item, having tried various combinations of parameters.

Can anyone help with this?